# Executing JS script on route change in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm working on a website orignaly developed in vanilla JS and JQuery.
Recently we've decided to upgrade our UI to Angular and typescript.
We use piwik to monitor our clients activity and the piwik module was made in pure JS. My problem is that whenever the route changes in the site i need to run the piwik script again (in order to bind the piwik events to the components) but the script is'nt executed again because the sites hav'nt refreshed. 
What i want is to manualy execute the script from the typescript (using JQuery perhaps). All the solutions i saw was to manuylay remove the script from the dom and then add it again but it seems like a hack, is there any way i can execute the script with webpack/JQuery/Any other technology?

Comment: I've used https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2 with Piwik in the past

Comment: I don’t want to rewrite the piwik script, all I want is to find a way programmatically execute it with typescript

Answer (score 1):

The Angular Router itself provides an observable stream.

You could create a route guard that subscribes to the route, when a `NavigationEnd` event occurs invoke your logic.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

.....

this.router.events
      .subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          console.log('NavigationEnd:', event);
        }
      });
```

It might be worth reading up on [Router Events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events)

Assuming piwiki exists in the global scope, you could invoke it using an `InjectionToken`

I am not familiar with this package at all, however something like:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const PWIKIPLUGIN = new InjectionToken('PWIKIPLUGIN');
```

And then invoke it with your constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(PWIKIPLUGIN) private pwikiPlugin) {}
```

This should give you the ability to invoke `pwikiPlugin.something()`

Comment: But how do I execute the script itself?

Comment: I am not familiar with the package itself, is it currently invoked in anyway within your Angular code? eg piwik.run()

Comment: Currently I have the script and I add it to the “scripts” :[] part in my angular.json file